# I can't change my php version on ubuntu/apache

Tags: php, apache-2.4, ubuntu-20.04

I have 2 versions of php installed now:

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo update-alternatives --list php
/usr/bin/php8.0
/usr/bin/php8.1
```

With cli the version is:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/php# php -v PHP 8.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2022 09:39:52) (NTS)
```

With **phpinfo()** I have **PHP Version 8.0.22**.

I read a couple of threads and I tried to switch the version with these commands:

1)

```
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar8.1
sudo apachectl restart
```

2. 

```
sudo a2dismod php8.0
>> ERROR: Module php8.0 does not exist!
sudo a2enmod php8.1
sudo apachectl restart
```

3. 

And at the end

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
There are 2 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php8.1   81        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/php8.1   81        manual mode
```

But nothig of that worked for me.

Comment: Run `a2dismod` without any arguments. It will list the loaded modules and ask which one to disable.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider `Your choices are: access_compat alias auth_basic authn_core authn_file authz_core authz_host authz_user autoindex deflate dir env fcgid filter mime mpm_prefork negotiation php8.1 proxy proxy_fcgi reqtimeout rewrite setenvif socache_shmcb ssl status
Which module(s) do you want to disable (wildcards ok)?` I don't see php8 :(

Comment: Is Apache configured to use PHP via fcgi? This should be visible in the VirtualHost configuration in Apache.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider In **phpinfo()** I have **Server API  FPM/FastCGI**. I have configured fcgi, but It's possible that in the process I done something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache is configured to connect to PHP 8.0 via FastCGI. But you are trying to enable 8.1 as an Apache module.

Decide which interface you want to use and either modify your FastCGI configuration to point toward the 8.1 service, or disable the FastCGI configuration and enable the 8.1 module instead.

You can't use both.